# How limited is open recursion in protocols with associated types?

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I have problems with my Swift code. It can't have been compiled because swift doesn't see associated types in some protocols. I have found essential minimum to reproduce the problem and the following code represents it.

```swift
protocol Woman {
    associatedtype Husband: Man
             where Husband.Wife == Self
}

protocol Man {
    associatedtype Wife: Woman
             where Wife.Husband == Self
}

protocol CoolWoman: Woman //warning
   where Husband: CoolMan {
}

protocol CoolMan: Man
   where Wife: CoolWoman {

    associatedtype Bike: Harley
             where Bike.Owner == Self
}

protocol Harley {
    associatedtype Owner: CoolMan
             where Owner.Bike == Self
}
```

After this code compilation I have the following warning in line that is marked with `\\warning` :

> Redundant conformance constraint 'Self': 'Woman'

It looks wrong because removing of `: Woman where Husband: CoolMan` makes code uncompilable, so conformance constraint isn't redundant. The warning makes the code unclear but (uh ok) it can be tolerated. But the fact that the function below isn't compilable can't be ignored.

```swift
func partnerBike<She: CoolWoman>() -> She.Husband.Bike? { //error
    return nil
}
```

It provides compilation error:

> 'Husband' is not a member type of 'She'

But it isn't true Husband is member of She that conforms CoolWoman. For me it looks like some processing removes constraints that has warning 'Redundant conformance constraint' from code before or while compiling.

Do I miss something about the protocol as the construct of Swift syntax?
Or it is just a bug of the compiler?
Why my code is uncompilable?
How to do it compilable?

---

Xcode 11.3 (11C29), Swift 5

Comment: You are clear, are you not, that in Z the `associatedtype SubY` has nothing at all to do with the X `associatedtype SubY`? These are completely unrelated placeholder names. You would confuse yourself (and others) a lot less if you used different names, since they are in fact unrelated placeholders.

Comment: @matt In real code, I have `Element` instead of both `SubY`. But you are right. I improved my example with better naming. Check it now.

Comment: ___removing of `where Husband: CoolMan` makes code uncompilable___ - compiles fine in my machine with the same Xcode you mentioned.

Comment: @nayem "How to do my code compilable?" means how to do it compilable without losing of declared design. In your solution Husband of CoolWomen isn't CoolMan, he has no Bike. So, the next function isn't compilable `func partnerBike<She: CoolWoman>(ms: She) -> She.Husband.Bike? { return nil }`. I changed function in my example to this one to provide better protection from misunderstanding.

Comment: This looks like you're trying to use protocols to reimplement some kind of class inheritance. That is a misunderstanding of protocols, and particularly protocols with associated types. The point of a PAT is to constrain other types in order to use them in generic algorithms. How many implementations exist of `CoolMan` in your shipping product? If it's one (and this looks like the kind of system that leads to having one implementation), then it's definitely a misuse of protocols. What problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: For example of what I mean by "reimplement some kind of class inheritance," I suspect you expect that `CoolWoman` ISA `Woman`, and that isn't true. Any type that conforms to `CoolWoman` must *also* conform to `Woman`, but `CoolWoman` is not a type. (This would be a lot easier to talk about with a more concrete case.) Almost certainly the thing you really want here are generics, not protocols.

Comment: @RobNapier I am finding the answer in the language context. Ok, I inherit Dog from Apple - it is wrong design, and OOP philosophy topic is very important... But why compiler doesn't give me ability to override virtual method from Apple in Dog when it is syntactically correct? - is about other things. I hope that my last editing  of the question and this analogy expose what I am asking about.

Comment: As others have said, you need to explain us your goal. You ask for advice on how to make the code compile, however it may well be that the path you're going is not the right one. http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Protocols are not OOP, and are not an implementation of inheritance; if you're trying to create inheritance, you should use classes (but Swift encourages you not to use inheritance at all). Protocols do not create virtual methods; they have protocol witnesses which are not the same thing. You seem to be trying to treat PATs as types, and they are not full types in Swift.

Comment: All that said, you have probably found a bug in the compiler, and I suggest opening a report at bugs.swift.org. You probably cannot solve this directly; you've bumped into one of the many sharp edges of the protocol system. But you almost certainly should not be trying to solve it this way. What you're trying to do here is probably a bad design. The compiler probably should compile it anyway, but it does not.

Comment: @RobNapier I know that the protocol isn't class. For me, it is a contract. `Class : Protocol` means that Class signed Protocol as a contract, and compilation will check that Class conforms signed contract. `Protocol2 : Protocol1` means that to conform Protocol1 is necessary to conform Protocol2 with correctives in 'where' block too. What is wrong with my understanding? As for me, my code has no conflict with this. But the compiler doesn't agree. I am trying to understand why. I don't see the syntax problem in my code.

Comment: @Cristik I have started to redesign my solution after had found this problem. But I continuously want to know what is wrong. I extracted the essential minimum of code to reproduce the problem and asked the current question. I don't ask about design or good or bad approaches, I just asked about language and compilation. My target is described in my question. I don't know what I can add, maybe - my target it is knowledge.

Comment: As I said, I believe this is a compiler bug. You are hitting a corner case of protocols that the compiler can't handle. This is common when you make very complicated protocol relationships in Swift. The compiler is quite buggy around these, and in many cases is missing features. As a separate issue, I believe you should redesign. But the answer to the question is "because the compiler can't handle it." I could not find a precise duplicate bug at bugs.swift.org, and so I suggest you open a report. (I suspect it will be a duplicate, but it's not obvious to me of which bug.)

Comment: @RobNapier Thank you. I already opened https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11997. About my example, it was specially created for the question. In my real code, this problem is a result of the inter-association of tens protocols. It wasn't easy to identify the root of it. Some correct design can follow the described structure, it is easy to imagine other naming with elements, containers, and generic algorithms instead of CoolMan and Bike. It is just a misleading example. I'll add another one later.

Comment: @RobNapier I was thinking about a better example, but as a result, I have the opinion that the current one is acceptable. It is just a part of some system, that isn't fully presented. It can be a video game with different units including different Men, CoolWomen and models of Harley. And of course, the gameplay has generic algorithms. The current design has no conflict with POP. "OOP dinosaurs" aren't everywhere where questions about Swift protocols are =)

Comment: Protocols (particularly PATs) should be driven by the algorithms you would write against them. Most good PATs wind up having names that include "-able-". (Collection is a bad name for a good protocol. It's properly "Indexable;" similarly Sequence is really "Iterable.") It is natural to think about classes in terms of what they "are." But protocols are properly thought about in terms of what they are able to do. And "Man" does not capture that. That is what I mean by you're thinking in terms of inheritance rather than protocols.

Comment: Longer version: https://youtu.be/DXwJg0QTlZE

Comment: @RobNapier Thanks for the video. All the following is simplified. Java and C# have two kinds of encapsulators: classes that contain algorithms and interfaces that contain signatures. So we have three kinds of inheritance: inheritance of abstraction (Interface2: Interface1), implementation (Class: Interface) and inheritance of realization (Class: Class). While most people think that OOP is about last one kind of inheritance I don't use this one (except cases when some third party doesn't give me a choice) - it is another one kind of OOP (OOP′) that isn't rooted in stereotypes from C++ time.

Comment: @RobNapier And I don't see the big conceptual differences between OOP′ and POP. But POP code is more complicated,  especially nets of PATs and сrushing of logic between extensions. I don't believe that -able- naming is something principal. I don't believe that Generic Type Argument is better than dependency by Generic Interface Type (Ok it is better for some cases, but not for all. Why is it good to use it everywhere?).

Comment: @RobNapier I think different. Maybe I think wrong. But it is impossible to convince me at this point, that's why I avoid discussion about design principles (the current situation is an exception) and ask only about syntax. Sorry for expression, I don't have aggression, I just wanted to say.

Comment: @RobNapier I use Swift during one year for pet project. I like Swift. Swift syntax has very interesting concept, but I can't feel it, becouse compiler implementation limits Swift, it like modern airplane that can't fly, only rides on the ground.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is right on the spot there, you do have a redundant conformance, the problem is that it has only place to remove the duplication, however that breaks other stuff, as you noticed.

The problem is caused by the circular references between the `Woman`/`Man` family of protocols, due to the constraints on their associated types.

`Woman.Husband` conforms to `Man`, `Man.Wife` conforms to `Women`. Now `CoolMan` is derived from `Man`, which means that `CoolMan.Wife` is already a `Women`. Specifying that `CoolMan.Wife` is a `CoolWoman`, and `CoolWomen` is a `Women` leads to the `Women` requirement being satisfied from two different paths, thus the redundancy compiler warning.

This is somewhat similar to the diamond problem, where the compiler can't choose which inheritance path to follow.

The solution here is to find another design that doesn't revolve around so many circular dependencies. Like with retain cycles, you need to break the chain of references somewhere, and this place depends on what you want to accomplish with this design.

Comment: After removing `Harley` from the design and `Bike` from `CoolMan`, circular dependencies that you described as the root of the problem still exist, but the problem (including the warning) does not.

Comment: @ValentineZakharenko Interesting, I don't know why the compiler doesn't complain after removing the `Harley` requirement, as the dependency cycle is still there. Likely it's due to internal implementation details of the compiler. You might've discovered an edge case there, pushing the compiler limits sometimes leads to odd results :)